# Finding covariance of two negative binomial distributions

Tags: probability

Take a set of random variables $X_n$ which indicate number of tosses of a coin ($P(H)=p$) to achieve $n$ heads. What is $\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_5)$?

I reasoned that the number of tosses till the first heads is not going to affect the number of tosses for the next four. So I can split $X_5$ into $X^{'}_1+X^{'}_4$ which are the number of tosses to get the first and latter 4 respectively of $X_5$. Since those two are independent, $\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_5)$ becomes $\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X^{'}_1)$. Since $X_1$ and $X^{'}_1$ are the same, $\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X^{'}_1)=\operatorname{var}(X_1)=\frac{1-p}{p^2}=\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_5)$

Is this reasoning sound?

Comment: Yes. From en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Sum_of_geometric_distributions you can see that $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are iid geometric random variables with probability $p$ of success. Then $Cov(X_1,X_5) = \sum_{i=1}^5 Cov(Y_1,Y_i) = Cov(Y_1,Y_1)$.

Comment: It is fine. The introduction of $X'$ is unnecessary, $X_5=X_1+X_4'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered: Yes, the argument is sound.

Comment: Great! Thanks all.